# Can I combine Demiplane, Glyph of Warding, Simulacrum, and Wish to have unlimited clones and spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, traps, wish, simulacrum

My intention here is to combine these four spells to let me amass an essentially infinite number of Spells through infinite Simulacrum  whilst maintaining RAW and RAI rules. Please note why my combination presented won’t work with citations from either whom or where you are getting your information. Everything below is assumed to have enough provisions (Food, Water, Beds, etc) to survive and the character level is of a level capable of casting all spells listed below.

Step 1: Create and enter your own Demiplane full of your Provisions.
Step 2: Wait 24 hours.
Step 3: Cast Glyph of Warding at an 8th level, Cast Simulacrum into Glyph of Warding vía Wish Spell. Set it to trigger when I step on it and click my ruby red slippers 3 times.
Step 4: Wait 24 Hours.
Step 5: (Now with full spell Slots) Step on Glyph and click my ruby red slippers 3 times.
Step 6: New Simulacrum is formed, Simulacrum uses 8th level Slot and 9th level spot to cast an 8th level spell, replicating step 3.
Step 7: Simulacrum proceeds to waste all of it’s spell slots Creating Glyphs or casting spells for me without me having to do anything other than provide material components.
Step 8: Simulacrum has used all spell slots, I Proceed to Glyph and (Per RAI) my old Simulacrum is destroyed and a New one of me with all of my spell slots is made.
Step 9: Sit back and enjoy infinite spell slots essentially.

Other than the caveat of having a 200GP cost for my Glyph of Warding every time, is what I said feasible albeit lengthy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This doesn't quite work the way you say

Most of your technique tracks with the rules, but Step 3 does not.

> Cast Glyph of Warding at an 8th level, Cast Simulacrum into Glyph of Warding vía Wish Spell.

*Wish* is a 9th level spell, and *glyph of warding* specifies:

> If you create a *spell glyph*, you can store any spell of up to the same level as the slot you use for the *glyph of warding*.

So, you cannot store a 9th level spell like *wish* in an 8th level *glyph of warding*.

**However**, you *could* simply store *simulacrum* (a 7th level spell) in an 8th or 9th level *glyph of warding*, and this plan works fine. It would just take 12 hours (casting *simulacrum*) and "powdered ruby worth 1,500 gp" in addition to the 200 gp cost of the *glyph of warding*.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that Wish is only replicating the effects or the spell selected without need of VSM components and not casting the lower level spell without VSM?

Comment: @BloodySprinkles When you cast *wish*, it is still casting a 9th level spell even if it replicating a lower level spell.

Comment: @BloodySprinkles You're correct. The issue is that _wish_ does not actually cast the lower-level spell; it replicates its effect. _Glyph of warding_ requires you to cast it for real.

Comment: If the character has the Boon of High Magic they could do it by casting two 9th level wishes to replicate Glyph of Warding and Simulacrum.

Comment: @Illustro that's just overkill, but would in theory work.

Comment: It's more to do it without needing to provide the material components for the spells. So you can get infinite free glyphs of warding with free simulacrum cast in it, while respecting the 1 simulacrum at a time convention.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't require nearly this much effort.  Simulacrum is a touch spell.  You can just have your first simulacrums wish-cast simulacrum on you directly.  When you want more 9th level spells, you can have a bunch of your older simulacrums get around your latest simulacrum for 12 hours and cast the original version.  You might have to make sure to stagger them right to handle the issue where your simulacrums are going up in puffs of snow from having their casters recast simulacrum, but once you've done that you're clear because nothing happens to the simulacrums cast by those who were dispersed.

Admittedly, this does mean that you have to pay the 1500 gp cost for actual-casting simulacrum for each 9th level spell slot you want to generate via this method, but that's a bit beside the point.  The point is that simulacrums casting simulacrum are broken, and the game doesn't account for them.  That's true.  You have spotted it.

[This series of unofficial tweets](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/09/17/if-i-cast-simulacrum-my-duplicate-lack-of-7th-spell-slot-that-i-used-to-create-him/) has Chris Perkins (Senior Producer) saying, in essence, "Yes, Simulacrums can cast simulacrum. Wish abuse? What?" followed by running away. I think that's about as good as your going to get for a "It looks like these rules might just be broken" confirmation.

Comment: That isn’t RAI. It’s been said that you cannot have more than one Simulacrum at a time. Hence why I had to come up with said complicated solution.

Comment: @BloodySprinkles The simulacrum wish-casting simulacrum on you should still work as long as it still has a 9th level spell slot though.

Comment: @BloodySprinkles - "RAI" is a messy, messy thing.  It's true that a single caster cannot sustain more than one simulacrum at a time, but this plan doesn't do that - each simulacrum is a different caster.  Is there a place that you're aware of where someone indicates that that is not allowed or should not be allowed?  I haven't seen it, and it seems like it would be a useful add to your question.

Comment: I could’ve swore that I read a tweet from Jeremy Crawford or Mike Mearls about the intentions of not possessing more than 1 Simulacrum at a time from a singular spellcaster and the context made it sound as if your Simulacrum couldn’t either but I cannot find such a tweet so I may be mistaken.

Comment: @BloodySprinkles It looks like someone asked the question on the twitter thread from one of Crawford's previous simulacrum answers, but he never responded.

Comment: Sageadvice.eu is basically just a guy who is consolidating all of the tweets from the various game devs (and answers some questions himself.) [Sage Advice](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice) is published rules errata and 'answers'. See the intro to both documents when you open them for more info.

Comment: @NautArch ah.  Thank you.  How is it now after the tweaks?

Answer (score 0):

It's way easier than that. As a level 20 wizard, you have 2 level 7 spell slots. So, you have to cast *simulacrum*, creating one with just 1 level 7 spell slot, then wait 24 hours and order your first simulacrum to cast *simulacrum* on you. Now you have 1 simulacrum with no level 7 slots and 1 with all the slots. From this point on you just create tons of simulacra in few days.

Note that it is the simulacra that cast *simulacrum* on you, not you casting it yourself. So they all can exist, obeying one another. But, you can solve the problem of command by just giving them some sort of Asimov's laws, like:

1. protect and fight for the original no matter any other order from now on
2. obey the original above all except rule 1
3. protect and fight for yourself, without violating rules 1 and 2.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: This is commonly known but from my understanding is against the intention of the spell for Simulacrum, hence why I included the RAI mention in the question.